# Stuck on a page passing a newhire_id from Asp to Angular website using Python Flask backend

Tags: python, asp.net, angular, flask

This is my asp code where I'm calling my localhost to my Angular backend trying to test this.

```
strPostUrl="http://localhost:5000/api/pass_newhire?id=" & intNewHire_id
%>  
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>NewHire to WOTC</title>
        <link href="resources/eighthr-app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/calendar.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body text="#333333" link="#000033" vlink="#000066" alink="#CCCCCC" leftmargin="0" 
     topmargin="0" bgcolor="<%=StrPageBg%>">
    <form name="Arc_SendToWotc" method="Post" action="<%=strPostUrl%>">
```

This is what I have in main.py (Flask backend)

```
@app.route('/api/pass_newhire', methods=['POST'])
def pass_newhire_id():
   newhire_id = request.args.get('id')
   # Example: Fetch newhire_id from the database based on the provided id
   # Replace this with your actual logic to retrieve the newhire_id
   newhire_data = {"newhire_id": newhire_id, "redirect_url": '/language_select'}  # Include 
   redirect URL in the response
   return jsonify(newhire_data)
```

It only return the url page : http://localhost:5000/api/pass_newhire?id=66568

and this on the page {"newhire_id":"66568","redirect_url":"/language_select"}. I want it to navigate to my language_select component. Any resons why this not working?